# Terraform keeps re-applying route changes even though code didn't change

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've setup new AWS environment, building everything from scratch and can't figure out why TF keeps applying same changes over and over. These are my route definitions:

```
# Routing tables to route traffic for Private Subnet
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  count  = var.az_count
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = element(aws_nat_gateway.gw.*.id, count.index)
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.250.0.0/23"
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.eni_vpn01.id
  }

  tags = merge(
          { "Name" = "${var.environment}-${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}-rt-private" },
          var.default_tags,
          {"eo:ops:type" = "networking"}
        )
}

#Route for Internet Gateway
resource "aws_default_route_table" "main" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.vpc.default_route_table_id

  route {
    cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id            = aws_internet_gateway.ig.id
  }

  tags = merge(
          { "Name" = "${var.environment}-rt-public" },
          var.default_tags,
          {"eo:ops:type" = "networking"}
        )
}
```

Here is output of a run. When I look at routing tables, nothing changes so this is very weird for me.

```
# aws_default_route_table.main will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_default_route_table" "main" {
        id                     = "rtb-048986295f3176afa"
      ~ route                  = [
          + {
              + cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              + core_network_arn           = ""
              + destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              + egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              + gateway_id                 = ""
              + instance_id                = ""
              + ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              + nat_gateway_id             = "igw-0eb25ccd5ca0e25bf"
              + network_interface_id       = ""
              + transit_gateway_id         = ""
              + vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              + vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          - {
              - cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              - core_network_arn           = ""
              - destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              - egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              - gateway_id                 = "igw-0eb25ccd5ca0e25bf"
              - instance_id                = ""
              - ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              - nat_gateway_id             = ""
              - network_interface_id       = ""
              - transit_gateway_id         = ""
              - vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
        ]
# aws_route_table.private[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
        id               = "rtb-05663bf0dfd235ee7"
      ~ route            = [
          - {
              - carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              - cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              - core_network_arn           = ""
              - destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              - egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              - gateway_id                 = ""
              - instance_id                = ""
              - ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              - local_gateway_id           = ""
              - nat_gateway_id             = "nat-0247c9d9ea5115e39"
              - network_interface_id       = ""
              - transit_gateway_id         = ""
              - vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          + {
              + carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              + cidr_block                 = "10.250.0.0/23"
              + core_network_arn           = ""
              + destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              + egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              + gateway_id                 = ""
              + instance_id                = ""
              + ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              + local_gateway_id           = ""
              + nat_gateway_id             = ""
              + network_interface_id       = "eni-0f1229f477f2357e7"
              + transit_gateway_id         = ""
              + vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              + vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          - {
              - carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              - cidr_block                 = "10.250.0.0/23"
              - core_network_arn           = ""
              - destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              - egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              - gateway_id                 = ""
              - instance_id                = "i-001701ea138a13f54"
              - ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              - local_gateway_id           = ""
              - nat_gateway_id             = ""
              - network_interface_id       = "eni-0f1229f477f2357e7"
              - transit_gateway_id         = ""
              - vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          + {
              + carrier_gateway_id         = null
              + cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              + core_network_arn           = null
              + destination_prefix_list_id = null
              + egress_only_gateway_id     = null
              + gateway_id                 = null
              + instance_id                = null
              + ipv6_cidr_block            = null
              + local_gateway_id           = null
              + nat_gateway_id             = "nat-0247c9d9ea5115e39"
              + network_interface_id       = null
              + transit_gateway_id         = null
              + vpc_endpoint_id            = null
              + vpc_peering_connection_id  = null
            },
        ]
# aws_route_table.private[1] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
        id               = "rtb-01869968b33811cca"
      ~ route            = [
          - {
              - carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              - cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              - core_network_arn           = ""
              - destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              - egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              - gateway_id                 = ""
              - instance_id                = ""
              - ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              - local_gateway_id           = ""
              - nat_gateway_id             = "nat-09cb92ac75a925a43"
              - network_interface_id       = ""
              - transit_gateway_id         = ""
              - vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          + {
              + carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              + cidr_block                 = "10.250.0.0/23"
              + core_network_arn           = ""
              + destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              + egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              + gateway_id                 = ""
              + instance_id                = ""
              + ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              + local_gateway_id           = ""
              + nat_gateway_id             = ""
              + network_interface_id       = "eni-0f1229f477f2357e7"
              + transit_gateway_id         = ""
              + vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              + vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          - {
              - carrier_gateway_id         = ""
              - cidr_block                 = "10.250.0.0/23"
              - core_network_arn           = ""
              - destination_prefix_list_id = ""
              - egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
              - gateway_id                 = ""
              - instance_id                = "i-001701ea138a13f54"
              - ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
              - local_gateway_id           = ""
              - nat_gateway_id             = ""
              - network_interface_id       = "eni-0f1229f477f2357e7"
              - transit_gateway_id         = ""
              - vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
            },
          + {
              + carrier_gateway_id         = null
              + cidr_block                 = "0.0.0.0/0"
              + core_network_arn           = null
              + destination_prefix_list_id = null
              + egress_only_gateway_id     = null
              + gateway_id                 = null
              + instance_id                = null
              + ipv6_cidr_block            = null
              + local_gateway_id           = null
              + nat_gateway_id             = "nat-09cb92ac75a925a43"
              + network_interface_id       = null
              + transit_gateway_id         = null
              + vpc_endpoint_id            = null
              + vpc_peering_connection_id  = null
            },
        ]
```

I am using TF AWS provider 4.30. and I am running TF standalone version 1.2.8.

Comment: Something did obviously change, and looking at the output it is this: `- instance_id                = "i-001701ea138a13f`.

Comment: It's the instance which network interface is specified in the code.

Comment: Ok, but that one seems to have changed from having a value to being an empty string. That's where I would look for. :)

Comment: Well how would you explain `aws_default_route_table` change? From same to same :)

Comment: Don't know, I guess it could be a bug in the provider. You can look for it in the GitHub issues.